# TikZ inside pgfplot axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tkz-collection

I am trying to use the TkZ command MarkRightAngle in an axis environment, however I cannot get it to work. I get a "Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!" error and "Line 21: Package pgf Error: No shape named B is known.". An possible solution would be matching the axis and canvas scales (but I have no idea how to do that) and adding the commands outside of axis environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tikz, ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,patterns,decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,shadows,shapes.misc,calc,%
positioning,% intersections}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetkzobj{all}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{pgfpicture}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsb}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsb}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbolsb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[  axis lines =center,
disabledatascaling,
anchor=origin,
    xlabel = $x$,    ylabel =$y$, 
ymax=4, ymin=-8, xmax =8, xmin=-4,
ytick={-6, -4, ...,4},xtick={-4, -2, ...,6},]

\addplot [   color=black, dashed,]
 coordinates {(-2,-5) (7,-5)} ;

\addplot [ color=black, dashed,]
 coordinates {(7,-5) (7,-2)} node[label=above:{$T(7,-2)$},circle, fill, inner sep=2pt] {};

\addplot [color=black,]
 coordinates {(7,-2) (-2,-5)} node[label=below:{$S(-2,-5)$},circle, fill, inner sep=2pt] {};

\tkzDefPoint(7,-2){A};
\tkzDefPoint(-2,5){B};
\tkzDefPoint(7,-5){C};
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please highlight code by inserting 4 spaces in front of each line (or you mark everything and press the {}-button. In order to get propper help here, you should complete your example to make it compilable. It should start with `\documentclass{` and end with `\end{document}`, should be as short as possible and show your error.

Answer (score 7):

`tikz` inside plot `axis` is not a general problem.  However, `tkz-euclide` has a completely different set-up for coordinates etc.  For labelling the right-angle it is easier just to use the `calc` library.  I have named the two nodes you are interested in by adding `name=A` and `name=B` to their options.  Then I have drawn the right angle symbol via

```
\coordinate (X) at (A |- B);
\draw ($(X)!5pt!(A)$) -| ($(X)!5pt!(B)$);
```

You can change `5pt` to some other dimension to get a different size mark.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines =center,
    disabledatascaling,
    anchor=origin,
    xlabel = $x$, ylabel =$y$, 
    ymax=4, ymin=-8, xmax=8, xmin=-4,
    ytick={-6, -4, ...,4}, xtick={-4, -2, ...,6}]
    \addplot [color=black, dashed] coordinates {(-2,-5) (7,-5)} ;
    \addplot [ color=black, dashed] coordinates {(7,-5) (7,-2)}
    node[label=above:{$T(7,-2)$},circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,name=A] {}; 
    \addplot [color=black] coordinates {(7,-2) (-2,-5)}
    node[label=below:{$S(-2,-5)$},circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,name=B]
    {}; 
    \coordinate (X) at (A |- B);
    \draw ($(X)!5pt!(A)$) -| ($(X)!5pt!(B)$);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you just killed 2 birds with one stone. I wanted to use node names for another diagram today with a separate issue.

Comment: This only works if the angle one wants to mark happens to be aligned with the coordinate axes.

Comment: @Hyperplane That was what the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternate solution. The above solution was giving me issues if the right angle was not on a horizontal or vertical line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymax=4, ymin=-8, xmax=8, xmin=-4,
    ytick={-6, -4, ...,4}, xtick={-4, -2, ...,6}]

    \addplot [dashed] coordinates {(-2,-5) (7,-5)} ;

    \addplot [dashed] coordinates {(7,-5) (7,-2)} node[pos=0,name=R]{}  node[label={[shift={(0,-0.2)}]{$T(7,-2)$}},,circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,name=T] {}; 

    \addplot  coordinates {(7,-2) (-2,-5)}  node[pos=1,label={[shift={(-0.5,-1.3)}]{$S(-2,-5)$}}, ,circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,name=S] {}; 

\coordinate (U) at ($(S)!(T)!(R)$); %using node R distorts the right angle symbol

  \end{axis}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(T,U,S)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your solution in 3D, and although the program compiles well the coordinates are way off. How can I export coordinates out of the axis environment? Thanks.